# Transaction Isolation level different threads massive number of Writes

Tags: sql-server, transactions, bulkinsert, isolation-level

I have a lot of threads that writing to DB some data in two tables. **tbl_raw_data** and  **tbl_parsed_data** where **tbl_parsed_data** have foreign key to **tbl_raw_data**.

I also need the writing to be very fast.

While checking the options on improving the writes (assuming reading time is nu so important) a friend of mine told me that I need to check the Transaction Isolation Level that is appropriate for my logic.
after reading some articles regarding this issue what I understand is that this property influence reading.

Is there a Transaction Isolation Level that affect writing? Which isolation level is "best" for lots of Threads running on lots of connections?

Am I looking in the wrong place?

What can I do to improve massive writing?

I'm using SQL server, the threads are coming from TomEE server that writes data that came via HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

The isolation level indeed does not affect writes. Locking has a negligible performance impact most of the time anyway (except if you block). You're thinking into a direction which is not fruitful. To convince yourself of that put the server under load and profile it using PerfView. Most of SQL Server's code will be spend (de)serializing data.

Research the well-known bulk insert techniques in SQL Server. From the clients that's basically `SqlBulkCopy`. On the server it would be `INSERT` statements with huge batches (or just one such statement).

Transactions generally improve performance because they allow the (inevitable) log writes to be deferred and batched.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that this property influences reading.

**But the point to be noted is it creates different locks for reading, writing at different levels row, table level etc. The problem with locks is they consume resources and slow down considerably. Depending on your requirement if you do not mind 'Dirty Reads', 'Non Repeatable Read' and 'Phantom' reads, you can set the isolation level to 'Read uncommitted'**.

I cannot vouch for the exact performance improvement, but definitely for a large parallel continuous read/write data it should be at least 10X from the default setting.

**There is another way to look at the problem:**

Sometimes if there are continuous multiple concurrent requests coming in, there would be too much load on your database. You still can design based on you requirement (always have to consider reads in designing). The effective solutions have always been the batch processing.

- You can always collect data from multiple requests and run transactions in a batch. That way it will be faster for that particular isolation level.
- Do you really require transactions? Agreed that you have foreign key relationships but you can always commit the **tbl_raw_data** rows first then the **tbl_parsed_data** row data.

Comment: Read uncommitted has no impact on write locks. Write locks are required by the engine to guarantee rollback.

Comment: I am not saying to use that Isolation level, its always the design based on the requirements.

Comment: Well its still a transaction even if its a 'Read uncommitted' isolation level, so it should be capable of 'roll back' according to the definition of transaction.

Comment: That "definition" is implemented by locks that cannot be turned off.